# Ability to set the font to italics in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Does anyone know how to set the code text editor font style to italics in Visual Studio 2005 or 2008? Note, I'm talking about the code editor not in code itself.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you want to do this?  I don't have any answers to offer, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to do this, unless there's some undocumented registry setting, would be through the environment automation modules.  I know [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) will italicize certain things if set up that way, so it must be possible.

I would start with Microsoft's [automation samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2005/aa718337.aspx) and see what you can find.  (I've made this a community answer so that if anybody wants to investigate further they can.)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot through the standard IDE options, the editor only allows you to change the font or set it bold.

Your best bet would be to use a font that only has italic characters (make sure that all chars take the same space).

Comment: Your suggestion about an italic-only font is a good one, but your absolute "cannot" is incorrect and you should either qualify it ("cannot through the standard IDE options") or remove it from your answer.  I don't know how Whole Tomato did it but clearly it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Example: change regular consolas font to italic font.

close all application and visual studio. go to C:\windows\fonts\consolas\ and remove regular font.

restart visual studio you will see text editor italic fonts.

Answer (score 0):

If someone's still looking for a solution:
You can find and download the Font you wish to use its Italic Type face and install only the `***Italic.ttf` or `***Italic.otf`

This way you do not install any other variation of that font aside from the italic. Go to Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors

On the dropdown select your preferred font!

Here's a nice one
https://github.com/willstocks/FiraCode2iScript/blob/master/FiraCodeTwoiScript-Italic.ttf